# JAXB parse complex xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

**I want to get the id, Age, name in customer node and listType, contact from customers node.**

**My sample Xml format is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customers>
<values>
<type>
<customer id="100">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>mkyong</name>
</customer>
<customer id="140">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>chandoo</name>
</customer>
</type>
</values>
<listType>Population</listType>
<contact>phani</contact>
</customers>
```

I created folloing pojo classes **(Customers, Values, Type, Customer)**

Customers.java

```
@XmlRootElement( name="customers" )
public class Customers {    
    List<Values> values;    
    private String listType;
    private String contact;
    Setters & Getters
}
```

Values.java

```
class Values {    
    List<Type> type;
    Setters & Getters
}
```

Type.java

```
class Type {    
    private int id;
    private List<Customer> customer;
    Setters & Getters
}
```

Customer.java

```
class Customer {    
    private String name;
    private int age;
    Setters & Getters
}
```

Main class in 
App.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            File file = new File("D:/userxml/complex.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class,Values.class,Type.class,Customer.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();            
            Type type = (Type) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);            
            System.out.println(type); 

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
```

I am PHP Developer and new to java. Please help me out. I want to get the customer details

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @BetaRide I edited my question. can you provide help url or answer for this query. TQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customers customers = (Customers) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

This will create the Customers object with the structure defined in your class, you can use the appropriate getters to fetch the value you need.

To answer the question in your comment, try (This is just an example with hardcoded calls for first element in the list):

```
        System.out.println(customers.getValues().get(0).getType().get(0));
        System.out.println(customers.getValues().get(0).getType().get(0).getCustomer().get(0).getAge());
        System.out.println(customers.getValues().get(0).getType().get(0).getCustomer().get(0).getName());
```

Call the appropriate getters and iterate the lists for the Customer object inside Type.

Comment: Initially I tried in that pattern and get the listType, Contact values from Customers node. I want to get the name, age values in customer node in the type node aswell. which is my problem.

Comment: JAXB will unmarshal based on the xml and the structure you have. Please check my edit in my answer. You can get the values by calling the appropriate getter (I've included one example).

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting the name,age in inner customer node.

Comment: Please paste the output of the sysout commands I've put in my answer. I am able to run this code and see name, age etc

Comment: The problem is I added anotation(@XmlElementWrapper(name="customer") ) for the getCustomer in Type.java class. How I can do, If I want to loop names and age. Tq alot.